# Math mode in tabularx

Tags: math-mode, tabularx

I would like to write a sum in my tabularx environment.
Usually I would go into the full math mode with $$\sum_i ...$$ and the "i" would be right below the sigma symbol.

However, this doesn't work inside the tabularx and if I instead use $\sum_i$ I can compile without an error, but the index for the i is on the bottom right of the sigma instead of right below.

How can I make the sum symbol with the index below the sigma inside of a tabularx?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want large operators you can use `$\displaystyle ... $`. If you want text style operators but with limits above/below, then `\sum\limits_{...}$`.

Comment: Your question is not limited to a `tabularx` environment. The same issue arises in *any* inline-math situation.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for!